# Trying to run Stanford Core NLP server causes 'could not find or load main class' error

Tags: java, ant, stanford-nlp

So I downloaded and unzipped the stanford corenlp tools version 3.5.2. I was able to run the command line version fine by running:

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP
```

but I can't get the server version to work. I tried running

```
java -cp "*" -Xmx2g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

but get the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class     
       edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

When I extract the files from both stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-sources.jar and stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar they both seem to be missing the StanfordCoreNLPServer.class file, even though on the github repo, that file exists in the pipeline directory.

I also tried adding the StanfordCoreNLPServer.java file from github and recompiling but then I get unknown symbol issues when running ant.

Any help would be appreciated in getting the server version up and running, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

The CoreNLP Server is being released in the next version of CoreNLP, and is not in version 3.5.2 yet. You can run it now by cloning the entire GitHub repository and compiling the project from source. To create a single jar, you can run `ant jar` from the checked out directory.

Answer (score 1):

The new version of Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 has been released, and the server should work fine with this new version.

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html

Answer (score 0):

So I'm just going to post this here in case anyone else comes across trying to do the same thing.

I was able to get it to work by un-jaring the main jar file and replacing the SRC directory of the download tool with the src directory from the github, then adding all the external jars from the "lib" directory of the github to the main directory of the tool. Then recompile by following their instructions here:

To extract the code source files

```
mkdir src
cd src
jar -xf ../stanford-corenlp-<version>-sources.jar 
cd ..
```

The code would get extracted to the `src` directory

Recompiling the code base:

```
ant
cd classes ; jar -cfm ../stanford-corenlp-<version>.jar ../META-INF/MANIFEST.MF edu ; cd ..
```

For running ant, make sure you have ant installed and `ANT_HOME` set.

Then from the main directory I ran

```
java -cp "*" -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer
```

and the server worked at `localhost:9000`.

Obviously this isn't the right way to do it and if you're reading this you should probably follow Gabor's answer or just way for the next version of CoreNLP to be released.